# Add a single exe in given directory to PATH environmental variable

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

Is it possible to add a single program among many in a directory to the PATH environmental variable?

Say I have a bunch of programs in `D:\utils`. Rather than adding `D:\utils\` to `PATH` I want to add `D:\utils\utility-5.exe`. This doesn't work though.

Is there a way to add it alone, or do I need to move it into its own directory?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(Note: I know this is almost 3 years old, but I landed on this page by searching a similar question, so I'm writing the correct answer here for anybody else coming here)

Yes, it is possible, it's even preferred to do this instead of cluttering the PATH variable. You need to add a key under the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` (for the machine) or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` (for the user - preferred).

The format is the same in both cases, the key name should be `utility-5.exe` and the registry default value should be `D:\utils\utility-5.exe`.

There are more information (including several more stuff you can do) [on MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration) and by [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110725-00/?p=10073)

EDIT: (some years later):

This won't (by design) work with Command Prompt (cmd) or PowerShell. In the case of PowerShell, you'll want to add a new alias in your `$PROFILE`, like so:

```
Set-Alias -Name vlc -Value 'C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe'
```

In the case of Command Prompt (cmd.exe), there's similar functionality with DOSKEY:

```
DOSKEY vlc="C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
```

This way you don't need to deal with the `PATH` variable at all.

Comment: I will try this. Is there any utility to automate this operation?

Comment: Well, it's the registry. I'm sure there are a million ways to automate it.
You could make a `.reg` file (by hand, or with any programming language or text editor). You could use PowerShell. You could use any other scripting language.

Comment: I meant if any program or script has been already written for this specific task, so that I won't have to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: It's just two entries in a registry file. It's literally 4 lines of powershell: https://gist.github.com/gschizas/61588cd258a76f7e23ffbded7182c28c

Comment: Just seeing this... this answer

Comment: So my .exe is in the registry. That doesn't mean it's on the PATH. I don't know why this has upvotes; it doesn't work.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge it does work. It's not supposed to be in the PATH _variable_, but if it's in the registry, you can run it regardless.

Comment: This does not seem to work on Windows 10 1803

Comment: For example I found out that some programs have already made paths in the regirsty, like opera (the web browser) but when I type in opera.exe in CMD, it doesn't work. It says not found. Althought the default value is set correctly and the key is opera.exe

Comment: @Shayan It does work. This method has been working since Windows 2000 (and probably even earlier than that). Look [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration) for more info.

Comment: cmd and powershell seems only lookup command from PATH, use ShellExecuteEx need call start/Start-Process

Comment: this does not work and any other app in that registry path is not available as a command

Comment: @EliavLouski it does work, just not from PowerShell (or Command Prompt), because PowerShell only looks in the PATH (not even the current directory) for security reasons.

Comment: @gschizas so how would you make this work on windows Cmd or powershell

Comment: @EliavLouski In PowerShell it's very easy, just add an alias to the command in your `$PROFILE`. No need to mess about with this old-school PATH stuff. In Windows Command Prompt (cmd), there's a similar functionality with DOSKEY (which, as the name implies, has existed since the MSDOS era, specifically since MS-DOS 5.0).

In both cases, you don't really need to take up space in the valuable PATH variable just for a single executable.

Answer (score 3):

You can't add a single executable to the path. There may be an alternative to moving it to another directory, though - assuming it's on an NTFS partition, you could create a symlink to the executable in a directory that is in the path using the mklink command.

Comment: I regret upvoting this, this is a bad idea, making symlinks will cause the working directory to be the shortcut path and not the target path. This means if the executable depends on other files like dlls, it won't be able to find them and will most likely fail to run or not be fully operable.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to put it into a directory.

All the entries in your `PATH` variable must be directories to be useful.  `cmd.exe` and any other shell or application that uses `PATH` will try to find the executable corresponding to any command you type by pasting the name of command onto the end of each `PATH` directory in turn until it either finds the command you asked for or it runs out of directories in your `PATH`. Any entry that doesn't exist or isn't really a directory will never match anything.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to create a separate directory that you add to %PATH% and then use a symbolic link to include the .exe file within said directory.

However if the .exe needs external files (like a .dll) to operate, you'd need to include that in the directory as well.

If you choose to do this I recommend the Link Shell Extension tool for Windows so you don't have to make the symbolic links in the command prompt.